# why are subgroups defined based on group homomorphisms rather than on its law of composition?

Tags: abstract-algebra

i am getting reacquainted with Algebra after some time. I thought i had understood it the last time, but apparently not. The question vexing me is why are subgroups (like the kernel) of a group defined on the basis of a homomorphism rather than its internal law of composition? Is every subgroup of a group a kernel of some homomorphism? Is it possible that a subgroup which is a kernel of some homomorphism not a subgroup when it is evaluated on another homomorphism? Please forgive the naivette. Its difficult to grasp things when one is doing self-study.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: The usual definition of a subgroup makes no reference to the concept of a homomorphism. In fact kernels are too special — they correspond exactly to the _normal_ subgroups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the definition of a subgroup **is** defined on the basis of its internal law of composition, and those subgroups which are defined on the basis of some homomorphism are defined as *normal* subgroups.
And there are a lot of subgroups which are not normal: for example, the group $A_5$ is simple; this means that there are ***no*** non-trivial normal subgroups of $A_5.$
Finally, yes, it is possible that the kernel of one homomorphism might not be the kernel of another homomorphism; e.g. $C_2\triangleleft C_4,$ where $C_n$ means the cyclic group of order $n,$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $f:C_4\rightarrow C_4$ defined as $f(x):=x^2.$ But $C_2$ is not the kernel of the homomorphism $g:C_4\rightarrow C_4$ defined as $g(x):=x^3.$
If you still have confusions, feel free to point it out!

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes it a lot more clearer, thank you. So, the subgroup structure still exists even when seen outside the homomorphism. The homomorphism only serves to highlight the subgroups, got it, .....finally.

Comment: @user297814 I have no idea what you're trying to say in your comment.